# difference between APDU command between contact and contactless Interface

Tags: smartcard, javacard, contactless-smartcard

I have a question about APDU format in contact and contactless Interface. I have an ACR122U contactless card reader and i studied it's API (v2.1). According to the document, apdu format in contactless mode is different from contact mode. for example SelectApplet command in contact mode is:

```
Command >> 00 A4 04 00 09 [A0,00,00,03,08,00,00,10,00] 00
Response <<61 19

Command APDU >> 00 C0 00 00 19
Response APDU <<61 17 4F 06 00 00 10 00 01 00 79 0D 4F 0B A0 00 00 03 08 00 00 10 00 01 03 90 00
```

but in contactless mode is:

```
Command APDU >> FF 00 00 00 12 d4 40 01 00 a4 04 00 09 a0 00 00 03 08 00 00 10 00 1a
Response APDU << 61 20   

Command APDU >> FF C0 00 00 20
Response APDU << d5 41 00 61 17 4f 06 00 00 10 00 01 00 79 0d 4f 0b a0 00 00 03 08 00 00 10 00 01 03 90 00 90 00
```

But when i search on web, they mentioned that there is no difference between APDU format. Am i wrong and there is another solution to send APDU to contactless interface?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing concepts. I'll try to make it a little clear.

*Disclaim: I'm not sure about some of the following lines!*

**A) Card Type**

There are two kinds of Dual Interface cards:

1. Dual Interface Dual Chip.
2. Dual Interface Single Chipe.

[image]
AS you see above, regarding the type of the card, you may receive equal, or different responses for a specific command that is sent to the card through different interfaces.

*Available cards are usually Dual Interface Single Chip. It is also notable that a Dual Chip Dual Interface can configured in way that have equal responses for equal commands on different interfaces.*

**B) APDU Handler Entity**

In Java Cards, the applet that is receiving the APDU commands, can decide to respond equal or different to a specific incoming command based on the interface that the command is received from.

For example, the applet that is shown in the below snippet, in respond of APDU Command = `00 10 00 00 00`, returns "Contact" when the interface is contact, and returns `Contactless` when the interface is contactless:

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.*;

public class TestApp extends Applet
{
    private static final byte[] data = { (byte)'C', (byte)'o', (byte)'n', (byte)'t', (byte)'a', (byte)'c', (byte)'t',
                                    (byte)'l', (byte)'e', (byte)'s', (byte)'s'};

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
    {
        new TestApp().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
        {
            return;
        }

        byte transportMedia = (byte) (APDU.getProtocol() & APDU.PROTOCOL_MEDIA_MASK); 
        boolean isContactless = (transportMedia == APDU.PROTOCOL_MEDIA_CONTACTLESS_TYPE_A) || 
         (transportMedia == APDU.PROTOCOL_MEDIA_CONTACTLESS_TYPE_B);

        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
        {
        case (byte)0x10:
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            if (isContactless){
                apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)0x0B);
                apdu.sendBytesLong(data, (short)0, (short)0x0B);
            }else{
                apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)0x07);
                apdu.sendBytesLong(data, (short)0, (short)0x07);
            }
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

}
```

Works as below:

```
Connect successful. # via the "Contact" Interface
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 00 00
Recv: 90 00
Send: 00 10 00 00 00
Recv: 43 6F 6E 74 61 63 74 90 00
Disconnect successful.

Connect successful. # via the "Contactless" Interface
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 00 00
Recv: 90 00
Send: 00 10 00 00 00
Recv: 43 6F 6E 74 61 63 74 6C 65 73 73 90 00
```

*Note that, Security Domain and Card Manager (The entity responsible for answering to SELECT APDU Command), usually have equal responses for both interfaces.*

**C) APDU Commands vs Pseudo APDU**

Card readers may supports reader features management/control commands. For example you can change the color of the LED, or delay of the beep sound. These commands that are supposed to be sent to the reader itself and not to the card are named Pseudo-APDU commands and usually are started with `0xFF` (I think the reader manufacturers choose this value because it is already defined in ISO7816-3 for PPSS in T=0 and for NAD in T=1, and so indicated as INVALID for normal applet commands).

The Specifications that the USB smart card readers are build based on it, is PCSC. You can download them freely from [here](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/overview.php). There is defined some Pseudo-APDU commands that usually reader manufacturers implement them in their products. They also may add some proprietary Pseudo APDU commands to their readers to add the capability to work with Memory Cards (SLE4432/42 for example) or to work with Mifare card.

The readers have a Pseudo-APDU command named *Direct Transmint* Command and it used to send a Payload to the card. For your reader, as you mentioned in the question, the Direct Transmit Command is as below:

[image]

*I'll add something here soon! ...*

Comment: Thanks from your response. I interpreted from your words: i make mistake to send my APDU command to card from pseudo APDU and i can send normal APDU (for example: 00 A4 04 00 09 [A0,00,00,03,08,00,00,10,00] 00) to card directly. Do i interpret correctly?

Comment: Yes, Simply send your select command to the card, using contact / contactless interface without any change.

Comment: But when i send select applet to card directly PCSC return "8010002F" error code. Why this happen?(my reader is ACR 122 U).

Comment: Are you sure that your smart card is ISO14443 compatible?(doea the reader makes a beep when the card brings in the reader RF field?) Which OS are you using? Which tool are you using to send APDU commands? Is firefox process open in your OS when you sent APDU to card? (If so, kill it in Task Manager and try again). What is the exact APDU command that you send?

Comment: 1- Are you sure that your smart card is ISO14443 compatible? yes, I tested by IDCore 3020 from gemalto. 2- doea the reader makes a beep when the card brings in the reader RF field? No, it doesn't make any beep. neither by IDCore 3020 nor by Mifare classic 1k.  3- Which tool are you using to send APDU commands? I have two tools, first is JSmartcardExplorer which is written by java and second a tool is SpringCard. Both of them return same result. 4- Is firefox process open in your OS when you sent APDU to card? No. it's not open. 5- What is the exact APDU command that you send?..... Next comment

Comment: (00 A4 04 00 09 [A0,00,00,03,08,00,00,10,00] 00) which works fine in contact mode and return "8010002F" in contactless

Comment: It doesn'i care by which protocol (T=0, T=1, ...) i connect?

Answer (score 3):

`FF` is basically an escape, usually used to send specific commands to the card reader. This reader reads the proprietary header, which is simply followed by the normal APDU. The APDU itself is indeed just the part after the 5 byte header (and after the 3 byte response header). For shorter (specific) APDU's they seem to perform some workarounds.

This could be a good option if the same reader (on a driver level) handles both contact and contactless protocol.

Comment: Some of these commands could also be part of the PCSC 2.01 specification, but currently I haven't got time to check.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can i send normal APDU to contactless card? (for example:  00 A4 04 00 09 [A0,00,00,03,08,00,00,10,00] 00)

Comment: Yes, no difference at all between contact and contactless when you are at APDU (=application) level!